# How do I get a Font Awesome icon to stick to the end of a paragraph and not below it

Tags: html, font-awesome

Title pretty much explains it. I'll put the code here.

```html
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
<i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i><p>text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here </p><i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

It's quotes around a paragraph by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could do this:

1. Put the i tag inside p tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
</head>
<body>
<p><i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
```

2. Or use CSS to style the html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
p{
display: inline;
}
</style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
<i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i><p>text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here</p> <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: putting it in my <p> tag worked but unfortunately my p class changes now apply to the icon, is there a way to get around this?

Comment: There is only one way and that is to override styles for the <i> tag. To remove a particular style property :   i { property: newValue; }

Answer (score 1):

```css
.para {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 45px;
}

.para:before,
blockquote:after {
  color: #EBB1B2;
  content: '\f10d';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 8px;
  display: block;
}

.para:after {
  color: #EBB1B2;
  content: '\f10e';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 8px;
  top: auto;
  left: auto; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-offset-2">
  <p class="para">text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here text here text here text here text here
    text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here text here text here text here text here
    text here text here text here text here text here text here text text here text here &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```